# Exposing ports on a network in docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

Using the Python docker client [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable), how do you create a container which is attached to a specific network, and exposes a specific port?

Ie the compose file may look like this:

```
  foo:
    ...
    expose:
      - "1234"
    networks:
      - my-network
```

We expose a port within my-network, without mapping it to the host.

Using docker-py's high level [containers.run](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) method only allows for Port Mappings (ie publishing ports externally) with it's `ports` kwarg, rather than simply exposing the port internally.
docker-py's low-level create_container method doesn't accept a simple network name to use.

How can the above compose file be replicated using docker-py?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Expose" as a verb hasn't meant much since Docker introduced multiple named Docker-internal networks.  You can delete this setting from your `docker-compose.yml` file and it won't affect anything; other services on the same network will still be able to reach yours.  That is, it should be enough to run

```py
client.containers.run('my-image', network: 'my-network')
```

From what I can tell the docker-py library never supported this option (even during the time when `--link` was the only way to connect containers, manual `--expose` was never that useful).  [docker/docker-py#2242](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2242) asks a similar question, with a similar answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! just tried our tests without `expose:` in our compose files and it indeed works!
Notes for anyone else reading this:
Containers on custom networks [automatically expose](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) all ports to each other, and no ports to the outside world. 
and
The docker EXPOSE instruction just functions as a [type of documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), it doesn't expose ports (user -p/-P for this)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.3/port-bindings/), you can pass the host ip, without the host ports, that will make your wish comes true.

```py
docker.utils.create_host_config(port_bindings={1111: ('127.0.0.1',)})
```